# Suggestion needed for Kubernetes cluster monitoring with ELK

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, elk

This message i am posting here to get some help or any links there.

We are using GCP and we have k8s cluster , usually people install ELK on top of K8s cluster, but in my case i want to install elk set up on different machine and then using this machine want to monitor k8s cluster ....
if you can help me if any document is there then help me with that, and then i will see how to give end points for k8s cluser etc

Thanks,
Mahendra

looking for any document if present to install elk set up on different instance then installing on k8s cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install the ELK stack on VM : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-elasticsearch

While on Kubernetes side you need to run the **two** **daemon** set :

- Filebeat
- Metricsbeat

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/master/monitor-kubernetes.html

So your stack will be running on the VM and **Filebeat** & **Meticsbeat** will be pushing data from the K8s cluster to VM where stack is running.

You can set up the network as per convenience keep both in the same VPC or whatever requiremenent.

Comment: Do I need to install it on top of Kubernetes master correct and it will take the information from node and push it back to ELK correct.

Comment: daemon set always run on nodes

Comment: Just one last few questions Harsh  -  1) this page will help me https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/master/monitor-kubernetes.html to perform POC as we already have cluster up and running in our dev environments. I will be using one Server in which I will install ELK.

Comment: yes or else you can use any other better doc however above doc will more give idea of architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application is running on k8s and has multiple nodes.

You can run filebeat on your application k8s cluster as a daemonset. This will create 1 instance of filebeat daemonset per node and ship logs like a sidecar.

In order to ship them to another cluster you must specify the ES endpoint in your filebeat daemonset manifest.

In case you are enabling SSL TLS then you must make sure your ES endpoint is accessible outside your ELK stack.